# htaccess subdomain redirect to port while keeping original url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have trouble getting this to work properly, what I'm trying to do is make
http://subdomain.domain.com redirect to domain.com:8080 while keeping the original url
"subdomain.domain.com"

Code so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1domain.com:8080$1 [L]
```

Which does the redirect, but browser url changes to "http://domain.com:8080" which is not what I seek.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to happen you need to enable `mod_proxy` in `subdomain\.domain\.com`. Once it is enabled try this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` of `subdomain.domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.(domain\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

Comment: "Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server."

mod_proxy was enabled in apache2 and should work.

Comment: Well my rule can't fix not found error. It is only proxying requests to `http://domain.com:8080/` (You can replace P by R to see whether it is redirecting to correct URL or not)

Comment: OOPS, user error, how stupid of me, this works perfectly now thank you!