# How to redirect to another domain But Not Show The URL redirection with .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-proxy

I am not sure if .htaccess can handling this, I do search a lot's of related topics, but find no solution.

What I need is:

when my users visit my site: **www.mysite.com**

actually they got content from **www.otherplace.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/page.html**

I would like user's browser address shows: **www.mysite.com** or **www.mysite.com/page.html** also fine for me, but not show's anything about the site: **www.otherplace.com....**

page.html is just single page, tiddlywiki, :)

thank you. :)

Comment: I'm afraid you must use proxy to change url without redirection

Comment: could you please let me know how to do "proxy"? I am a newbie, if you can go something detailed, that will be very appreciate. :) Thanks.

Comment: see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20721676/548225

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using apache this can be done with proxy.
Open `/etc/apache2/mods-available/proxy.conf` and add your's definition

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset off
                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://www.otherplace.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/page.html
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.otherplace.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/page.html

</IfModule>
```

I use similar configuration to host multiple services that listen on different ports (e.g. Jenkins, codebrag e.t.c)  with on http each with their own directory e.g

```
ProxyPass         /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
ProxyPassReverse  /jenkins  http://localhost:8080/jenkins
```

and the url is http://my.domain.com/jenkins/ instead of http://my.domain.com:8080/jenkins

Remember to restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart` or another equivalent

Rewrite is another option but IMO proxy is easier to set up although it's not so powerful.

Comment: hi, I am using a shared hosting service with bluehost, is this going to work in my host? i am bout to try everything you mentioned, till I red "restart apache", I think I have to confirm before I really go with yr method, as I think I haven't any permission to do the restart things, :)

Comment: Good idea. You can use [vagrant](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/provisioning.html) to quick set up server with apache on it. There could be a problem if somebody else edited apache configs, you'd better backup everything just in case. Restarting server in shared hosting is also bad idea but sometimes we really must change something.